# JavaScript that prints date and time with a link won't work

Tags: javascript, date, browser, printing, time

I'm currently enrolled in a JavaScript class at my community college, and we're supposed to create a page with the following:

"Today's date is (date)"

"Kids Club"

"The time is (time)"

Then, I don't seem to get this part, the instructions state: "Have a link to the new kidsnew.htm page that contains the text "Go To Kids Club". Use onClick and widow.location to open kidsnew.htm.
Before switching, you should use the navigator object and the method to test for the name and version of the browser. Display the name and version of the browser with an alert box and advise the user to upgrade for better results with the new page if their browser is out of date.
The kidsnew page should contain an HTML form button that will take you back to the "kidsold.htm" page."

So. I assume that I'll need the browser verification, where you can find in the first part of the code. I don't get what else I'm supposed to be using, as we were not told of a "onClick" method in the chapter's were reading. Can anyone help me refine the code and get it to display as stated? I did most of it correctly, I think;

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Kids Club</title>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "brwsniff.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
<!-- hide me from older browsers>


//==============================Browser Info=================================
var browser_info = getBrowser();
var browser_name = browser_info[0];
var browser_version = browser_info[1];
var this_browser = "unknown";
if (browser_name == "msie")
{
if(browser_version < 5.5)
{
this_browser = "old Microsoft";
}
else
{
this_browser = "modern";
}
}
//end

if (browser_name == "netscape")
{
if (browser_version < 6.0){
this_browser = "old Netscape";
else
{
this_browser = "modern";
}
} //end

</script>

//=========================End Browser Info============================

//==========================Start Date Script============================
var date = new Date();
//new is keyword for object Date
//
//getting info from object Date
//
var month = date.getMonth();
var day = date.getDate();
var year = date.getYear();
var hour = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
//january is month 0, think of arrays
//
month = month + 1;
//fix y2k
//
year = fixY2k(year);
//fix minutes by adding 0 infrotn if less than 10
//
minutes = fixTime(minutes);
var date_string = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
var time_string = hour + ":" + minutes;
var date = "Today is " + date_string";
var time = "The time is " + time_string;

//y2k fix
//
function fixY2k(number) {
if (number < 1000){
number = number + 1900;
return number;
}
//time fixer
//
function fixTime(number){
if(number < 10) {
number = "0" + number;
}
return number;
}
//========================End Time Script==================================

// show me -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type = "text/javascript">
<!-- hide me from older browsers
document.write(date);
</script>
//show me -->

<h1>Kids Club</h1>
<script type = "text/javascript">
<!-- hide me from older browsers
document.write(time);
</script>
//show me -->


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Um, that code is ancient. They have not upgraded the class in 12 years? FYI: They are teaching you wrong and out dated material.

Comment: @epascarello is very much right. If this is code _they_ gave you, they're wasting your time.

Comment: This is. We're using "The Book of JavaScript 2nd Edition" It's by David Thau, I believe.

Comment: I would still like some help, despite the old code. For me only the HTML of <h1> is showing up, and none of the rest of the code prints properly.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments:

```
> <script type = "text/javascript">
> <!-- hide me from older browsers>
```

That's rubbish, HTML comment delimiters were never needed to hide script element content, just remove them.

```
> var year = date.getYear();
```

You should use the [`getFullYear`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.10) method, it avoids the two digit year issue.

```
> var date = "Today is " + date_string";
```

There is no need to declare `date` a second time. It's not harmful, just unnecessary. `date` started out as a Date object, now it's a string. That's not good programming style, just modify the existing `date_string`, e.g.

```
date_string = "Today is " + date_string";
```

In the body of the page you have:

```
> <script type = "text/javascript"> 
> <!-- hide me from older browsers
> document.write(date); 
> </script>
> //show me -->
```

Note that the comment delimiters start inside the script element, then finish outside it. So the browser is left with invalid HTML and whatever happens next is a result of error correction (the same for the next script element too).

Fix that and you may have solved your problem.

Comment: **That's rubbish, HTML comment delimiters were never needed to hide script element content, just remove them.** -- not true.  Pre-javascript browsers (IE 1 & 2, Mosaic, Netscape 1) would render the text between the `<script>...</script>`.  You can say they haven't been needed in 15 or 20 years, however.

Comment: @jeremy—browsers were supposed to ignore elements they didn't understand ([HTML 2.0](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt), §4.2.1 Novermber, 1995). I can't test those ancient browsers to see what they do (did) but I don't remember rendering of script element content ever being an issue, I think I started with Netscape 1 or similar. Perhaps there was a short period where it was an issue.

Comment: Not ignore elements, ignore tags.  That is different.  The rules where that ancient browsers should ignore tags like `<div>...</div>` yet still render the contents inside.  This allowed the option to add new HTML tags.  `<script>...</script>` however, was the oddball, in that you wanted its **contents** suppressed too. Perhaps you either a) never used inline scripts or b) put the script element in the head instead of the body.